# Loading javascript content (a google chart) via ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-visualization

I'm loading a google chart on my page using https://github.com/winston/google_visualr, which returns  javascript with the chart content which looks like;

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(draw_geochart);
     function draw_geochart() {
        var data_table = new         google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn({"type":"string","label":"Country"});data_table.addColumn({"type":"number","label":"Visits"});data_table.addRow([{v: "United Kingdom"}, {v: 13}]);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart'));
                    chart.draw(data_table, {dataMode: "regions", width: 700, height: 500, title: "Company Performance"});
                  };
</script>
```

This works fine when rendered with the page but I can't get it to work via ajax, the correct response is sent but it won't appear on the page.
I'm loading it as such;

> charts.js.erb

```
$('#geochart').html("<%=  render_chart @countries_chart, 'geochart' %>");
```

the charts action on dashboard controller is called on page load;

> dashboard.js.coffee

```
ready = ->
      $.get 'charts'
```

Comment: How are you performing the AJAX, and what gets returned by the AJAX call?

Comment: the returned js is exactly as in the question same as what's returned with non ajax request, the ajax call is in the question, the dashboard.js.coffee file

Comment: I don't see an AJAX call in your question.

Comment: ready = ->
      $.get 'charts'

Comment: Ok.  What does that render as for javascript in the browser?  Open the page, view source, and post it.

Comment: If you are able to solve it?